# How do I make it so the updated value of a string stays, after the function has completed its job?

Tags: python

*How do I make it so the updated value of a string stays, after the function has completed its job?

This is what I'm doing:

Game is a string and index is a number:*

```
 def replace_character_at_index(index, game):  
          game = game[:index] + '+' + game[index + 1:]     
          print(game)

INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~' 
replace_character_at_index(4, INITIAL)
```

OUTPUT: `'~~~~+~~~~~'`

I want this new value for INITIAL to remain. But as seen below when I print it again, it goes back to its original value.

```
 print(INITIAL)
```

OUTPUT:

```
'~~~~~~~~~~'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing you should return the value and when you call the function you have to store a value in a variable for future use like this.

```
def replace_character_at_index(index, game): 
      game = game[:index] + '+' + game[index + 1:] 
      return game
INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~'
newValue = replace_character_at_index(4, INITIAL)
print(newValue)
```

Ouput:

```
~~~~+~~~~~
```

You can use the variable `newValue` as many times you want it will always print `~~~~+~~~~~`

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value generated by the replace_character_at_index() method, It will allow you to return the new string you want and reassign it to the old variable.

```
def replace_character_at_index(index, game):
   game = game[:index] + '+' + game[index + 1:]
   //print(game)
   return game
```

then simply reassign the value to the old one by using

```
INITIAL = replace_character_at_index(4, INITIAL)
```